# Graphic intersection to decide what kind of soil the crop is on

Tags: wms, vector, intersection

I have to create a graphic intersection that demonstrates what kind of soil the culture is on, for example:

[image]

Crop no. 1: soil type 12 gr/kg
Crop no. 2: soil type 9 gr/kg

Crop polygons are vector data from PostgreSQL via GeoServer

and the layer with the type of soil is a WMS from ISRIC

Can someone help me how to do this?

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: ISRIC does not use GeoServer, the software used is MapServer (https://maps.isric.org/)